# Incompatible types: Activity cannot be converted to LifecycleOwner

Tags: android, gradle, android-activity

these are my dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01'
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.2.0-beta01"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common:22.0.1'
implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:9.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'''
```

i have updated the androidx.appcompat:appcompat to the newest version(1.2.0-beta01) but the problem still not yet solved. Can anyone help me? I can provide more information as i have no idea which part of the code cause this error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the logcat please

Comment: 2020-05-05 23:03:30.485 9759-9759/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2020-05-05 23:03:30.485 9759-9759/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2

Comment: My android phone cannot be opened and the logcat only showed these error. I have tried to import tess-two into my project and this happened @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: OK, delete that dependency and try again

Comment: which dependency should i delete? I have no idea @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: my androidx.lifecycle.Observer not working anymore after updated some of the version of my gradle script but i am not sure which of them cause the problem.

Comment: Try without implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:9.1.0'

Comment: Without it your problem is solved?

Comment: after deleted the implementation the error  ( cannot convert to lifecycle) is still there

Comment: OK, please attach the error of logcat in question